# Meteor server side remote debugging

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2, remote-debugging

### Versions

I'm using Meteor 1.0.3 and node 0.10.35 on a small Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-3d50120d EC2 instance.

### Context

I know how to do server side debugging on my development box, just  $ meteor debug and open another browser pointing to the url it produces -- works great.

But now, I'm getting a server error on my EC2 instance I'm not getting in development.  So I'd like to set up a *remote* debug session sever side.

Also, I deployed to the EC2 instance using the Meteor-up package (mup).

---

### EDIT

In an effort to provide more background (and context) around my issue I'm adding the following:

What I'm trying to do is, on my EC2 instance, create a new pdf in a location such as:

> application-name/server/.files/user/user-name/pdf-file.pdf

On my OSX development box, the process works fine.

When I deploy to EC2, and try out this process, it doesn't work.  The directory:

> /user-name/

for the user is never created for some reason.

I'd like to debug in order to figure out why I can't create the directory.

The code to create the directory that works on my development box is like so:

> server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  checkUserFileDir: function () {
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    var dir = process.env.PWD + '/server/.files/users/' + this.userId + '/';
    try {
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.code != 'EEXIST') throw e;
    }
  }
});
```

I ssh'd into the EC2 instance to make sure the path

> /server/.files/user/

exists, because this portion of the path is neccessary in order for the above code to work correctly. I checked the path after the code should have ran, and the

> /user-name/

portion of the path is **not** being created.

---

### Question

How can I debug **remote** server side code in a easy way on my EC2 instance, like I do on my local development box?

Comment: Its a bit difficult to debug production instances, In production mode most of the helpful debugging stuff is removed to optimize for speed. You can run in debug mode but I'm not sure you would want this?. Mup defaults to using production mode so it can be difficult to do this with the setup as it stands. You can get basic logs using `mup logs`, though. Is this an app in production on your EC2 instance?

Comment: I can do what I like with this particular EC2 instance, so yes I can deploy in debug mode.  Mup is just how I deploy to that instance, the error has nothing to do with my mup deployment though.  I get the error when calling a server side Meteor method.  So I guess I'll need to know how to deploy in debug mode using mup, and how to attach a debugger to the server side while it's running on the EC2 instance.

Comment: @Akshat, I just updated the question (under the Edit heading) to give more context on the "why" I need to debug the EC2 instance.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems in my case, since I'm using Meteor-up (mup), I can not debug per-say, but get access to the remote EC2 instance server console and errors by using command $ mup logs -f.  This effectively solves my issue with being blind on the server side remote instance.  I'll post this as the answer when the time limit is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in my case, since I'm using Meteor-up (mup), I can not debug per-say, but get access to the remote EC2 instance server console and errors by using command $ mup logs -f on my development box.

This effectively solves my issue with being blind on the server side remote instance.

It still falls short of actual debugging remotely, which speeds up the process of finding errors and performance bottlenecks, but it's all we have for now.

Comment: And now we have `mup meteor debug`

Answer (score 3):

[Kadira.io](http://Kadira.io) supports remote errors/exceptions tracking.  It allows you to see the stacktrace on server side exceptions in the context of your meteor methods.

See https://kadira.io/error-tracking.html for more detail.

Comment: I had a conversation with the maker of Kadira.io after your post, where he pointed out I could use the command $ mup logs -f, to get server side visibility.  So many thanks @Manto!

Answer (score 0):

For someone who still searching:

@zodern added server-side debugging of meteor apps to great meteor-up tool:
https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/pull/976

Do `mup meteor debug` in deployment dir and you will be almost set, just follow the text.